# Cannot upload File + Data with Angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a issue where I need to upload a Object of data and a file to My asp.net WebAPI server. Previously the POST'ing of my object was working fine but now that I must upload a file with the object I'm having endless issues.

This is my service that accepts the supplier object and the file:

```
createSupplier(supplier: Supplier, file: any) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    var input = new FormData();
    input.append("file", file, file.name);
    input.append("supplier", supplier);

    return this._http.post(this._globalService.getURL() + "api/supplier", input, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
}
```

My WebApi Server:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/supplier")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddSupplier([FromBody]Supplier supplier, [FromBody] dynamic file)
    {
        var result = supplierSVC.AddSupplier(supplier);
        if (result.isSuccessful)
        {
            return this.Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { response = result.Message });
        }
        return this.Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { response = result.Message });
    }
```

I get the error:

> The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.

And:

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Supplier' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.

Really not sure what format to send my data in as its a mixed bag of data being sent. Any help would be grateful thanx

Comment: Are you getting a hit inside your web api server method ?

Comment: no, If i remove the properties then I can only receive via the Request.HTTP object